# read specific address in memory using C

Tags: c

could anybody explain me how to read DWORD ,WORD ,BYTE in C from specific address in memory?
for example, base address that is returned using MapViewOfFile() function,how can I read a consecutive BYTE,WORD, or DWORD using C ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the answer for C or C++?

Comment: @ Mats Petersson in C please

Comment: Please realise that there is no BYTE, WORD or DWORD defined in C. They probably are an artifact typedeffed by the windows programming environment. In C, you can just dereference *any* pointer type p by using `*p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapViewOfFile()` returns `LPVOID` which is a typedef of `void*`. You'll need a cast.

The easiest thing to do would be to read a byte at a time. You don't specify if there's any kind of performance requirement here (nor do you specify your platform, arch, etc), so I'll assume a "byte at a time" is ok.

Note: WORD is defined as short and should be 16-bits in Win32. DWORD is an int and should be 32-bits in Win32.

```
LPVOID pvAddr= MapViewOfFile(...);

BYTE* pBytes= (BYTE*)pvAddr;

BYTE firstByte= pBytes[0]; /* copy first byte */

WORD w;
memcpy(&w, pBytes+1, 2); /* copy the next two bytes */

DWORD dw;
memcpy(&dw, pBytes+3, 4); /* copy the next 4 bytes */
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: better to use markdown code blocks than trying to inject `<code>` tags directly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the address is aligned suitably for the datatype you are using - this is important as in some architectures, it's invalid to access an "unaligned" address!

In C:

```
void *address = MapViewOfFile(...);
DWORD *dword_ptr = (DWORD *)address; 
WORD  *word_ptr = (WORD *)address;
BYTE  *byte_ptr = (BYTE *)address;
```

In C++, the pattern is similar, but instead of a basic C style cast, you should use `reinterpret_cast<type*>(address)`, where `type` is `DWORD`, `WORD`, `BYTE`, etc. E.g.:

```
DWORD *dword_ptr = reinterpret_cast<DWORD *>(address);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your question has basically two parts:

1. could anybody explain me how to read `DWORD` ,`WORD` ,`BYTE` in C from specific address in memory?

   That's easy, but probably not what you want, you simply cast the address to a pointer of the desired type.

   ```
   DWORD x = *((DWORD *)address);
   ```
2. for example, base address that is returned using `MapViewOfFile()` function,how can I read a consecutive `BYTE`,`WORD`, or `DWORD` using C ?

   That's also not too bad. You are getting a `void*` from `MapViewOfFile`, simply cast it or assign it to an appropriate pointer type and then you can use it like an array:

   ```
   DWORD *p = MapViewOfFile(...);
   DWORD x = p[1]; // second DWORD of the mapped file
   ```

Comment: I think you mean second DWORD rather than second byte on that last line?

Answer (score 0):

[`MapViewOfFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx) returns an `LPVOID` (which is equivalent to a [`void *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987957/difference-between-lpvoid-and-void)) so it can be read like any other [pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).